# I want to know how many times a word (typed by the user) is in a sentence using substring in C#

Tags: c#

I want to know how many times a word (typed by the user) is in a sentence using substring in C#. I want to know how to catch words with the Substring function and the for loop.

```
string frase=txEntrada.Text;
string paraula=txEntrada2.Text;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++)
{
    string recorrer = frase.Substring(i, 1);
    if (recorrer == paraula)
    {
        count++;
    }
    }
    txSortida.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Substring is probably not the right way to do this. One way is you could do string.Split(‘ ‘) to split at spaces, and then exclude periods and other non alphanumeric characters, then count how many of those words match.

Comment: Your code has one too many closing braces (`}`).  I edited your code to make it more readable, and suddenly it was obvious

Comment: Look at [Regex.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.count?view=net-7.0) method. Available with .NET 7. `int count = Regex.Count(frase, paraula);`

Comment: If the word you are looking for is `tea`, and the word `instead` is in your text (i.e. "ins**tea**d"), does it count as a find?

Comment: What would you think that will happen if you split the original "frase" with the user input?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than extracting a substring at every possible starting position of the string, use [`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32)):

```
string frase = txEntrada.Text;
string paraula = txEntrada2.Text;

int count = 0;

int offset = -1;
while ((offset = frase.IndexOf(paraula, offset + 1)) >= 0) {
  count++;
}
```